# OneToMany with 2 ManyTwoOne

Tags: jpa

I have one class "User" that has some requests. Each request has 2 Users (sender and receiver):

```
public class User {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "?")
  private List<Request> requests;
}
public class Request{ 
  @ManyToOne ?
  private User sender;
  @ManyToOne ?
  private User receiver;
}
```

How I can map this?

Comment: @"User" that has some requests , In the code `User` has `Publication` not`Request` ? Is the question proper?

Comment: Was a mistaked. Edited

Comment: What do the `User.requests` contain? The requests where the user is `Request.sender` or `Request.receiver`?

Comment: This is for a web app. The logged user can send requests to other users. So if you are logged and send a request you are the sender and the other user is the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two references for `sender` and `receiver` inside `User`.

```
public class User {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
  private List<Request> senderOf;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
  private List<Request> receiverOf;
}
```